# pytelegrambotapi(telebot) pagination buttons

Tags: python, bots, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api, telebot

How to create an inline button pagination database is shown in this photo for example. but the names in the database should be put on the buttons, not numbers, and there should be 10 buttons on 1 page, of course there should be next and previous buttons, and X is not needed

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpczX.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

To create an inline button pagination in a telegram using Python, you can use the python-telegram-bot library

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

First of all, it's a bad question. You don't state your problem clearly.

Second if you want to display button can try to use the pytelegrambotapi types. InlineKeyboardMarkup ()
Or types. ReplyKeyboardMarkup ()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this doesn't actually answer the question. and your criticism of the question isn't very constructive. and answer posts are not supposed to be for judging the question.